# The link icon/plugin not showing in TinyMCE 5.0.14

Tags: tinymce

I configured TinyMCE (`community version 5.0.14`) like this:

```
<script>tinymce.init({
            selector:'textarea',
            plugins: "lists",
            plugins: "table", 
            plugins: "link",
            toolbar: "undo redo | styleselect bold italic | numlist bullist | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | outdent indent | link",
    });</script>
```

Which get me this:

[image: Link to image 1]

When I add image to plugins and toolbar like that:

```
<script>tinymce.init({
            selector:'textarea',
            plugins: "lists",
            plugins: "table", 
            plugins: "link",
            plugins: "image",
            toolbar: "undo redo | styleselect bold italic | numlist bullist | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | outdent indent | link image",
    });</script>
```

The image button is shown, but the link button disappears :

[image: Link to image 2]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to have multiple `plugins` items in your configuration object.  You want one single `plugins` value that contains a single string of all the plugins you want to load.

For example:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: "textarea",
  plugins: "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
  toolbar: "undo redo | bold italic"
});
```

The appropriate documentation is here: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/integration-and-setup/#plugins